# Use .apply to recode nan rows into a different value

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I am trying to create a new groupid based on the original groupid which has the value of 0, 1. I used the following code but it failed to code the nan rows into 2.

```
final['groupid2'] = final['groupid'].apply(lambda x: 2 if x == np.nan else x)
```

I tried the following code also, but it gave an attribute error

```
final['groupid2'] = final['groupid'].apply(lambda x: 2 if x.isnull() else x)
```

Could someone please explain why this is the case? Thanks

Comment: ah, yes. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.isnull` for check scalars if need use `apply`:

```
final = pd.DataFrame({'groupid': [1, 0, np.nan],\
                     'B': [400, 500, 600]})
final['groupid2'] = final['groupid'].apply(lambda x: 2 if pd.isnull(x) else x)
print (final)
   groupid    B  groupid2
0      1.0  400       1.0
1      0.0  500       0.0
2      NaN  600       2.0
```

`Details`:

Value `x` in lambda function is scalar, because `Series.apply` loop each value of column. So function `pd.Series.isnull()` failed.

For better testing is possible rewrite lambda funcion to:

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    print (pd.isnull(x))
    return 2 if pd.isnull(x) else x

1.0
False
0.0
False
nan
True

final['groupid2'] = final['groupid'].apply(f)
```

But better is [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
final['groupid2'] = final['groupid'].fillna(2)
```